# Does a Chinese citizen need a visa to transit Taiwan, Singapore, and Hong Kong?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, hong-kong, taiwan, chinese-citizens

I’m going to Hong Kong from Los Angeles using China Air Line. I have a Green Card and a mainland China passport. Am I allowed to make a transfer flight stop at Taiwan then to Hong Kong? My return flight will be from Singapore, stopping in Taiwan, then back to the US. Do I need a Taiwanese visa to catch my connecting flight in Taiwan, due to my mainland China status?

Comment: Are you just transiting in Taiwan or leaving the airport?  Do you have permit to visit Hong Kong?

Comment: Which airport? [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&modify=1) gives TWOV for passengers transiting through Taoyuan (TPE) and Kaohsiung (KHH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Comment: The onward flight looks a lot like a two-tickets itinerary. And just verified it, it's just not a single itinerary (I'd assume single CI to HKG and then another carrier to SIN)